# PIL: What is happening in Image.Blend() when I use an alpha greater than 1.0?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

From the docs:

> Creates a new image by interpolating between the given images, using a constant alpha. Both images must have the same size and mode. out = image1 * (1.0 - alpha) + image2 * alpha
>   If the alpha is 0.0, a copy of the first image is returned. If the alpha is 1.0, a copy of the second image is returned. There are no restrictions on the alpha value. If necessary, the result is clipped to fit into the allowed output range.

So there is no restriction on alpha, but what actually happens when you use values greater than 1.0?

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

The image blended with an alpha of 100.0:
[image]

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yup, but I wanted to understand the reasons behind the funky colors. I will edit the question with the resulting image.

Answer (score -1):

The results are fully explained by the formula you quoted. If `alpha` is `100`, you get `image1 * -99 + image2 * 100` and then the results for each pixel are clamped to be valid. Lets look at what that means for some example point.

A pixel I sampled from the joker's forehead has RGB value `(255, 194, 106)`. An approximately corresponding pixel from the other image (part of the seascape's blue sky) has RGB value `(1, 109, 217)`. Combining them according to the equation above, gives `(25401, 8609, -10883)`, which is obviously way out of bounds for all three bands. Clamping each color to be between `0` and `255` gives `(255, 255, 0)`, which is the pure yellow you see in the output image for that area.

Almost all of the pixels in the output image will have values of either `0` or `255` for each color band (resulting in very saturated colors). Only a very few pixels (maybe none for these images, I've not checked), where the difference between the two images was very small will there be any intermediate values.